# Vue v-if with laravel backend data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have an app which uses laravel for backend/api and vue components in views for frontend, this is a nice combo imo.

This is what I do right now:

```
@if(count($latestPosts) > 0)
    <div class="LAYOUTwrapper_section">
        <layout-title-2 :title="'Últimas publicaciones'"></layout-title-2>
        <post-list-1 :posts="{{ json_encode( $latestPosts ) }}" :title="'Últimas publicaciones'"></post-list-1>
    </div>
@endif
```

Now when I want to check if I should render a component (postsarray may be empty, then not render post component) I use blade conditional syntax, now this works but I'm thinking about moving this logic to vue components, keep blade syntax to minimum and handle this in the frontend with vue entirely.

Now my question is how can I check if a laravel array is empty in vue component placed on blade view file, not inside the component, basically I want to use `v-if` to  check if $posts ilength is more than 0 inside `v-if`

Bellow code doent't work but I'd like something similar.

```
<div class="LAYOUTwrapper_section" v-if="{{ json_encode($latestPosts).length > 0 }}>
    <layout-title-2 :title="'Últimas publicaciones'"></layout-title-2>
    <post-list-1 :posts="{{ json_encode( $latestPosts ) }}" :title="'Últimas publicaciones'"></post-list-1>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="LAYOUTwrapper_section" v-if="json_encode($latestPosts).length > 0">

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

#### Better Solution

**Really decouple your component** by moving the data behind an API and have your component request the information it needs from an endpoint. Your App/Wrapper/Component should be responsible of getting the data it needs.

#### Not so great solution

`v-if` expects a `Javascript` conditional, so you could just get your blade to render the HTML template as `v-if="true"` or `v-if="false"`, Note that if you mistakenly pass `"false"` instead of `false`, Javascript will interpret this as a `truthy` value, and the logic will break.

When vue takes over and renders the component, the `boolean` should kick in on mounted.

You can also pass the value as a prop to your component.
`<layout-wrapper :shouldDisplay="{{..}}" />` and use that on the `v-if`.

```
{
    template: `
    <section/>
        <div class="LAYOUTwrapper_section" v-if="shouldDisplay"></div>
    </section>
    `,
    props: {
        shouldDisplay: Boolean
    }
}
```